# Python: Get Surfaces from convex hull

Tags: python, convex-hull, pyvista

I am new to 3D-Calculations and i searched for a while, but couldnt find any solutions (maybe I am using the wrong search terms).

So i have different 3D-Point-Clouds - for example a "pyramid" with 5 points:

[image]

The array looks like this:

```
pts = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0],
                [0.5, 0.5, 1], ])
```

Now i want to extract all "surfaces" - my plan was to calculate the convex-hull but I couldnt find any properties to get the surface - i tested with scipy.spatial

```
hull = ConvexHull(pts)
```

For example i want following output:

```
surfaceCount: 5
surface[0]: [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0] (yellow)
surface[1]: [0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 1] (blue)
surface[2]: [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 1] (no color)
surface[3]: [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 1] (orange)
surface[4]: [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0.5, 0.5, 1] (green)
```

[image]

How can i calculate these "surfaces"?

Thanks
Mr.Dev

EDIT:
Ok, i thought my questions was specific engough - but here is my next try (i found the library "pyvista")

I have following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

points = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0],
                [0.5, 0.5, 1], ])


# points is a 3D numpy array (n_points, 3) coordinates of a sphere
cloud = pv.PolyData(points)


volume = cloud.delaunay_3d(alpha=5.)
shell = volume.extract_geometry()

surf = volume.extract_surface()
ug = surf.cast_to_unstructured_grid()
surf.plot()

pv.save_meshio("test.obj", surf)
```

This code generates me a *.obj file

```
# Created by meshio v5.2.2, 2022-01-16T16:44:24.834322
v 0.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 0.5 0.5 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
f 1 2 3
f 1 3 4
f 1 5 2
f 1 4 5
f 3 2 4
f 2 5 4
```

And shows me a plot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8axPa.png)

I expected to find 5 "faces" in this object file - but there are 6 - because the "Ground" is splitted into two triangles - entries:

```
f 1 2 3    
f 1 5 2
```

So my question is: Is it possible (maybe with pyvista), to generate an output file (doesn't matter if its an .obj file or something else) in which i can find exactly 5 "faces" for the pyramide?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I don't think what you're looking for can be done in general. Without knowing _a priori_ that the 4 points on the base are coplanar, any algorithm will be sensitive to numerical noise. Imagine if 3 points out of the 4 have a `z=0` coordinate, and the fourth one has `z=1e-15`. Then the base is not exactly a plane and you need two triangles. So: what are you going to do with the surfaces? Are you sure you need a square on the base? For instance you could colour the triangles by surface normal, and then both base triangles would have the same colour, appearing as a single quadrilateral.

Comment: Hi @Andras Deak, thank you very much. I think "face normals" was the correct keyword which i couldnt find - in my case, i shouldn't have problems with "numerical noise", but i think it would be very easy to filter it. In the pyramide-example, i get 6 "face normals", but 2 are identical, so I get exactly what i want. I also testet it with a cube and it was correct. And yeah, in the first step i want to color the triangles.

Comment: My point was more that it's difficult to do what you want in general, so I don't expect tools to do that for you. What if the base were a septagon? The library would have to figure out that there are five coplanar triangles matching up there! That's difficult. For instance you could start categorising your faces according to normal direction, then see if any faces with the same normals share nodes, and if they share nodes whether they tile to give a single face, _then_ replace the triangles with higher-order polygons. And repeat. I'm saying it's simpler to work around this and use triangles.

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped me to gain a deeper understanding of the problem! Now I can rethink my planned implementation. I can't upvote your comments cause my reputation is too low - but i will do this when im allowed to :)

Comment: If you have nothing against using R, you can do what you want with the **cxhull** package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need Delaunay. Moreover the faces must be given by the indices of their points.

```python
import numpy as np
import pyvista as pv

pts = np.array([[0, 0, 0], 
                [1, 0, 0], 
                [1, 1, 0], 
                [0, 1, 0],
                [0.5, 0.5, 1]], np.float64)
faces = np.hstack([[3, 0, 1, 4], 
                   [3, 1, 2, 4], 
                   [3, 2, 3, 4], 
                   [3, 0, 3, 4], 
                   [4, 0, 1, 2, 3]])
mesh = pv.PolyData(pts, faces)
mesh.plot()
```

---

```
mesh.area
Out[24]: 3.23606797749979
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution i am using now: in my raw-data i have the information about which points are needed for a face (i didn't see this information at the beginning). Now I use the "grouped points" to build seperated .obj files.